# Photoswipe with angularJS pswp undefined

Tags: angularjs, photoswipe

I am very much a beginner trying to make my first webpage.  I am using angular with angular route.  The page containing the required photoswipe html per the getting started documentation is injected into index.html.  Im getting the following error.  "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'firstChild' of undefined" which points to line 66 of photoswipe.js (var node = ....)

```
getChildByClass: function(parentEl, childClassName) {
    var node = parentEl.firstChild;
    while(node) {
        if( framework.hasClass(node, childClassName) ) {
            return node;
        }
        node = node.nextSibling;
    }
```

Following parentEL up through the code I end up with the very first line of the required js again per the getting started doc.

```
    var pswpElement = document.querySelectorAll('.pswp')[0];
```

adding console.log(pswpElement) returns undefined which i think is the root issue.  The doc says that class=pswp has to be the class of the root element for photoswipe.  It is in the root element of the html page being injected for /gallery in my route definitions.  I have also tried adding it to every element up to  including the div that contains ng-view in my index.html page.  pswpElement always comes back as undefined.

Any help integrating photoswipe with angular would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem, If you have jquery or some other javascript tools enabled, only run the photoswipe function, after the page has completely loaded.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    openPhotoSwipe();
});
```

You will need to encapsulate the photoswipe javascript in your html in a function, or move the javascript to the bottom of the page..

The "undefined" error comes because it tries to start searching for the .pswp classes when they are not loaded yet...